# mysql server or client

Tags: mysql

Why `mysql` server or client is not in `software` selection. It looks like the only way to install `mysql` is using `sudo apt install` command.

Comment: Sorry?!  It is in "security".  So is client. `sudo apt install` would not work if it wasn't in the repositories.

Comment: @Rinzwind - "software" means `gnome-software` - sorry for not being precise. There is no such thing as "security", and it is not shown as "installed" now that I have both server and client. The only thing is there is the MySql Workbench.